# Can I express the idea of a connected state block in the python equivalent of a checkov YAML policy?

Tags: python, checkov

I'm trying to write this example code in python rather than YAML and I haven't found documentation on how to perform a check on a connection state block. Is this possible in checkov written in python?

```
definition:
       cond_type: "connection"
       resource_types:
           - "aws_elb"
           - "aws_lb"
       connected_resource_types:
         - "aws_security_group"
         - "aws_default_security_group"
       operator: "exists"
```